# why the following code does not return match object?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

```
txt = 'is worth 12$'
pattern = re.compile('12$')
match = pattern.search(txt)
if match != None:
    print('ys')
else:
    print('no')
```

It prints `no`. I want to know why the string `'12$'` is not being matched.

Comment: Why do you wanna use a regex to find 12$ in a text. You can simply search for string 12$ . If you have a case to find any number followed by a $ symbol then you can write a general regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a special character in a regular expression. You should escape it like that:

```py
import re
txt='is worth 12$'
pattern=re.compile('12\$')
match=pattern.search(txt)
if match!=None:
    print('ys')
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex,
>   you need to escape them with a backslash. If you want to match 1+1=2,
>   the correct regex is 1+1=2. Otherwise, the plus sign has a special
>   meaning.

It should be:

```
pattern=re.compile('12\$')
```